# How to find RAM usage across org using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics

I am not sure if this is possible, I would like to find the RAM and storage usage of all the laptop registered to my org. All the laptops are running Win Pro and are visible in MS Azure.

Would appreciate it if someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Naym

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello @Naym Uddin, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should have **Enterprise Mobility + Security E5 Trial or Paid** licence to view the details of storage and memory uses of all laptops in your org or tenant.

[image]

Use the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to hit this API

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices`

and make sure you should have required permission consented.

[image]

After querying the above API you will see the require parameter as below

`totalStorageSpace` :  ,`freeStorageSpace`:
`physicalMemoryInBytes` :

For example response value you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-windowsmanageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-beta)